# What is meant with multiplication? Understanding problems

Tags: group-theory

> Think of $\mathbb{N}_0$ as a semigroup with multiplication as the binary operation.
>
> Give a subset $H\subset \mathbb{N}_0$, which is a semigroup with a neutral element, such that $e_H\not=e_{\mathbb{N}_0}$.
>
> (give both neutral elements)

I can't think of a semigroup where $e_{\mathbb{N}_0}\cdot a\not=a$.

I don't even know what is expected. Could you give me a not too spoiling hint?

Because if I don't include 1 (the neutral element of N) then my subgroup doesn't have a neutral element.

Also just to be sure $1=e_{\mathbb{N}_0}$ right? Since $a\cdot 1=1\cdot a=a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: There is just one such $H$, and it has exactly one element.

Comment: $\{0\}$? is this it?

Comment: @saturatedexpo: It is indeed.

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. Right, that prunes it down to only one